# rails how to get the following query in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I need  to get the following output in rails how do i do it?

```
SELECT "booking_rooms".* FROM "booking_rooms" INNER JOIN "bookings" ON "bookings"."id" = "booking_rooms"."booking_id" WHERE "booking_rooms"."room_id" IN (22, 27, 21) AND ("bookings"."start_date" <= '2016-10-16' AND "bookings"."end_date" > '2016-10-12')
```

I tried:

```
BookingRoom.joins(:booking).where(room_id: self.booking_rooms.map(&:room_id), bookings: { start_date:self.end_date,end_date:self.start_date})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For using conditions in a `where` statement please refer to the "[Conditions](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#conditions)" documentation.

Try this:

```
BookingRoom.joins(:booking)
        .where(room_id:self.booking_rooms.map(&:room_id)
        .where(bookings: { "start_date <= :start_date AND end_date > :end_date" },start_date: params[:start_date], end_date: params[:end_date])
```

Answer (score 0):

Using ActiveRecord [chaining](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#understanding-the-method-chaining) and [Array-Conditions](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#array-conditions) you can do something similar to:

```
BookingRoom.joins(:booking).
     where(room_id: self.booking_rooms.map(&:room_id)).
     where(bookings: { "start_date <= ? AND end_date > ?" }, self.start_date, self.end_date)
```

Comment: When quoting from another source it's _really_ important to provide proper credit.

Comment: sure, @theTinMan you are right! i was a bit tight on time. updated.